# How do I get the list of servers where the user has bot permissions

Tags: discord, discord.py, quart, pycord

so I'm working on a discord bot dashboard with pycord and quart and now I need to make a page similar to this [image]from https://mee6.xyz. The tricky part is that I can't figure out is getting a list of all the servers where they have elevated permissions even if the bot isn't in them. Thanks for any solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I ended up coming up with is this `render_template("select.html",servers=[[guild.icon_url,guild.name,guild.is_owner,guild.id,True if guild.id in bot.guilds else False] for guild in await user.fetch_guilds() if int(guild.permissions.value) & 1 << 5 or int(guild.permissions.value) & 1 << 3], logged_in=[True,user.avatar_url,user.name])`

where more specifically `int(guild.permissions.value) & 1 << 5` tells  while looping through `await user.fetch_guild()`